# Common-mode input range for differential amplifier

Tags: transistors, mosfet, amplifier

I am trying to simulate the following differential amplifier as per a [laboratory practical I found](https://my.ece.utah.edu/%7Eccharles/ece3110_2007/Labs/Lab1.pdf). [image]

I am trying to understand the common-mode voltage input range of a differential amplifier. According to the Sedra and Smith textbook, The minimum common-mode input voltage is determined by "the voltage to keep the current source at the source terminal of the differential amplifier, operational". The attached link indicates potentiometer R7 must be varied until the current indicated by PR1 is 80mA which I have done. Upon varying the common-mode voltage to the differential amplifier input terminals (to voltages as low as 300mV), I observe no change in the drain currents through them. What I expected to occur, was failure of the amplifier of some sort to indicate that the current source was not working properly, such as the drain currents splitting unevenly. I am confused as to how one would obtain the input common-mode voltage range in this case. Any help will be appreciated as I am just aiming to understand the basics.

Thanks

Comment: *such as the drain currents splitting unevenly* Explain **why** you would expect that, considering that this part fo the circuit is 100% **symmetrical** You're not applying any (differential) signal, what would happen if you did? Also think about the **mode of operation** Q3 needs to be in to allow it to behave like a good **current source**. What if the voltage on the drain of Q3 gets very low?

Comment: Why are there specification of "frequency" at some points ? It is a DC steady circuitry.

Comment: Some indications, as frequency, are not needed. It is a steady state circuit. For searching common mode input range, change R3 still ouputs PR2 and PR3 change a little (linearity). If "common mode" is "good", PR2 and PR3 will "quasi" not change.

Comment: @Antonio51 The frequencies included are provided by default, by the multisim probe. That has nothing to do with anything at this point, as you know.